# Trying to pass filter variables inside of pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I have a view called Reorder.  It's a list view that basically shows all the supplies available.  The list is so long, that we had to implement pagination, so that the page would load without timing out. That works great.

We also have a filter (textbox) where the user can enter a number, and filter the list to see only the supplies that have a stock of equal or less than that desired amount.  In theory, that works fine with the above mentioned filter.

Problem is that - When the user opts to move beyond the first page of results, the filter remains in place, but the stock number gets dropped and all supplies, regardless of stock amount start showing again.

I have tried a few different ways, but can't figure out where to add the searchstring within the pagination code, for it to carry through to any page the user jumps to.

Here is my Reorder Controller Code

```
    public ActionResult Reorder(string searchString, int? page)
    {

    var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID).ToList();


    int searchValue;

    // If searchString is null (or not an int), then set our searchValue to int.MaxValue
    if (!int.TryParse(searchString, out searchValue)) searchValue = int.MaxValue;

    // var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && s.OnHand.Value <= searchValue);
    var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand < searchValue);

    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));

    }
```

The searchstring is passed from the view to the controller and used to bring back results where OnHand is equal or less than that value.  searcstring ultimately gets convered to searchvalue.

Should I be adding searchvalue somewhere in this line?

```
var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using Viewbag to pass the variables within the @HtmlActionLink, therefore including the filters on each page change.  Previously, I was sending an unfiltered model via @HtmlActionLink, which is why it failed.

Here is my working Controller

```
{

        var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID).ToList();

        int searchValue;

        // If searchString is null (or not an int), then set our searchValue to int.MaxValue
        if (!int.TryParse(searchString, out searchValue)) searchValue = int.MaxValue;

        // Set Viewbag for filter

        ViewBag.searchString = searchValue;

        var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand < searchValue);

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
       // return View(catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand < searchValue).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
        return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));

    }
```

And the relevant code from the View:

```
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">
<p>
    Stock Inventory Less Than: <input type="text" name="searchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

</p>
```

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Reorder", new { page, searchString = ViewBag.searchString }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not answering your question with this, but for the sake of performance you should move the `.ToList()` method to a later point in code. Read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/implement-efficient-data-paging) about efficient paging with Linq. Before the `.ToList()` method, also add your search value. Else the power of Linq is defeated again.

Chain up your searchValue where-clause with your first line:

`var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand < searchValue).OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID).ToList();`

And move that edited line below the `ViewBag.searchString = searchValue` line.

In fact, you should rewrite more of this code, but without plenty of time to serve up a good example, you better read the two links mentioned above. The point is you should do paging and filtering on the database.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide some useful information.  I am in the very beginning stages of learning MVC5, C#, Linq, (and Jscript and Jquery).  It has been a tremendous learning curve, and I appreciate your recommendations to help.  I will review the links and make appropriate changes.  Thank you!